# Will rand() and time() function cost a lot system resource?

Tags: c++, random

I am using the C++ `rand()` function in my program, but I found my program would be very slow when running it after I use `rand()` in a loop. The loop would iterate for many times, and will invoke function `time()` as the seed of `rand()`.

So I am wondering if C++ `rand()` and `time()` function cost a lot system resource?

Comment: Can't you just measure and find out?

Comment: Rand has modulus, multiplication and some sums so must take more time than a simple multiplication.

Comment: It depends on the implementation, and on what you consider "a lot".

Comment: You only need to seed once, usually.

Comment: Computational load strongly depends on the type of random engine used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536617/random-engine-differences/16537080#16537080

Comment: The fibonacci method seems faster.

Comment: @sje397 Really? I need to invoke `rand()` for many times, and I want it to be really random. Is just one seed enough?

Comment: @interjay what's the implementation of `rand()` in the `std` namespace? I would like to know how many CPU cycles one invocation would cost.

Comment: There are different implementations depending on who wrote your standard library. And calling `srand(time(NULL))` multiple times is actually worse than calling it once, and can lead to repeated sequences of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1 - You mentioned you seed rand() every loop iteration: that is not only not needed, as may reduce the performance of your PRNG (statistical performance), as they were designed to be seeded by the previous output. Seed your PRNG only once, and then call (only) rand(). It automatically updates the seed on each call.

2 - rand() is, indeed, slow. Depending on your statistical requirements, if not very strict, you can just reimplement a rand() funcion. A simple PRNG can be made from a [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your answer! I am wondering if there is any light-weight `rand()` or any library that I can invoke directly. I have no time to implement one by myself using the logistic map you suggested.

Comment: If you want a simple algorithm Tausworthe generators use a sequence of bit shifts, XOR's, and bitwise AND's, so they tend to be relatively fast.

Comment: Cool but what about time() ?