# Why old rand() faster than uniform_real_distribution in openMP?

Tags: c++, performance, random, parallel-processing, openmp

Can someone explain to me why second for loop, with old rand(),  executes a lot faster than the first loop? I have seen through multiple post here that using c++11 engine and uniform distribution are being recommended bacause rand() + multithreading is a perf bottleneck?
Also as suggested I have generator and function per thread.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    std::vector<mt19937> generators(omp_get_max_threads());
    std::vector<uniform_real_distribution<double>> functions(omp_get_max_threads());
    
    for (int i = 0; i < omp_get_max_threads(); i++)
    {
        // seed is random
        generators[i] =  mt19937(1654 + 17*i);
        functions[i] =   uniform_real_distribution<double>(0.0,1.0);
    }

    double itime = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for        
        for (int i =0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            int a = functions[omp_get_thread_num()](generators[omp_get_thread_num()]);
        }
        
    
    double end = omp_get_wtime() - itime;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    double start = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i =0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            int a = ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
        }
    double endR  = omp_get_wtime() - start;

    cout << "Generator: " << end<<endl;
    cout<<"Old: "<<endR << endl;
}
```

Comment: Also, to add. This code is built with gcc and executed on i9 processor

Comment: Do note that `rand` can be a very simple and very not random PRNG.  `mt19937` OTOH is a much more complicated and performance impacting algorithm and provides much more random number.

Comment: Simply put, `rand` just isn't very good.  Agree with @NathanOliver.

Comment: The execution time is different because the algorithm is different.  Related :  [Random Engine Differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16536617/327083), [What is the difference between a non-secure random number generator and a secure random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/101337/327083)

Comment: [Funny and interesting piece on just how bad `rand` is](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) along with alternatives..

Comment: also note that there are better PRNGs than the MT.  better in terms of both speed (e.g. cycles per byte, cache pressure, etc) and in terms of statistical properties (linear complexity being the most obvious).  a more recent paper on the MT is https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06437

Comment: Two million timed calls to omp_get_thead_num() aren't going to help performance, plus the results from rand() when it is executed in parallel are meaningless. You need to put the call to rand() inside a critical section for a fair comparison. (And on parallel random numbers looks at 
Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3 https://thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf)

Comment: Fully agree with @JimCownie Also note that even though you have separate `mt19937` instances for the threads, you most likely suffer from _false sharing_ since multiple instances are on the same cacheline.

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggest something like this

```
struct alignas(std::hardware_destructive_interference_size) Rng {
   std::mt19937 mers;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double>> dist;
};

std::vector<Rng> rngs(omp_get_max_threads());
```

And I vaguely remember that `omp` has a way to set a value for each chunk so the `omp_get_thread_num()` all the time, and that might also make it possible to make an ref to each struct Rng.